# How to convert list of historical local timestamps to UTC in q kdb?

Tags: kdb

I have a list of historical timestamps specified in London local time (GMT/BST). How can I transform these into UTC timestamps?

```
local_times:(2019.04.17T20:00:00.000;2019.01.17T20:00:00.000);
expected_utc_times:(2019.04.17T19:00:00.000;2019.01.17T20:00:00.000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your machine timezone(local time) is GMT/BST then you can directly use [gtime](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/gtime/) function.

```
q) local_times:(2019.04.17T20:00:00.000;2019.01.17T20:00:00.000)
q) gtime local_times
q) 2019.04.17T19:00:00.000 2019.01.17T20:00:00.000
```

From other timezones, you can use the method listed here: https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/timezones/

Comment: The link work perfectly thanks! In my case the machine timezone was not GMT/BST.